# How do I search for term in separate mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'd like to search multiple columns and multiple tables.

I imported all my tables into sqlfiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60689e/3

What I'd like to select is `user id, name_surname, avatar, from users table` Based on keyword, matching column "location" or "name_surname" in users table. This is relatively simple:

```
SELECT u.name_surname,
       u.avatar,
       u.location
FROM users u
WHERE u.location LIKE :kwd
OR u.name_surname LIKE :kwd
```

The tricky part for me is querying table for matches in **words_en** table, which essentially should be queried against connections table where I actually can see which user is associated with which word... How do I do this last part escapes me.

So I probably need to:

1. query words_en and find out if there is a match at all.
2. if there is a match I need to look at id of word_en word and see if this id exists in connections table.
3. Select distinct user_ids from connections table.
4. Select name_surname for the selected user_ids.

Thanks for looking.
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all users based on a search of the `words_en` table would look something like [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24756/5/0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name_surname, u.avatar
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id IN 
(
  SELECT c.user_id
  FROM connections AS c 
    JOIN words_en AS w 
    ON w.id = c.word_id
  WHERE w.word = 'word1'
    OR w.word = 'word2'
) 
AND u.location LIKE '%Nunya%'
  OR u.name_surname LIKE '%sandro%'
```

If you want to use the same search term for any of the three fields then use the following:

```
SELECT u.name_surname, u.avatar, u.location
FROM users AS u
  JOIN connections AS c ON c.user_id = u.id
  JOIN words_en AS w ON w.id = c.word_id
WHERE (w.word LIKE '%word1%'
  OR u.location LIKE '%word1%'
  OR u.name_surname LIKE '%word1%') 
  AND u.privacy = 3
```

Comment: This works, I also tested something similar :) I was close! But I need to merge results of your query, with the results of my previous query for location and name, so results come in together...

Comment: **@salivan**, easy fix, just add at the end of the query.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey, testing it. 1 question, keyword going inside query will always be the same for example w.word = 'word1', u.location LIKE 'word1'. Basically I want to get users for search term word1, no matter where it appears in location column or words_en. Atm this query doesn't work if I put same keyword in all spots.

Comment: This works 100% for words, but for username search returns same results several times: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24756/26. Why does it do that? Should I put DISTINCT?

Comment: ***@salivan***, DISTINCT would work, see [***example***](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24756/27/0).

Comment: awesome! Thanks :) I want to add a strict rule, AND u.privacy = 3. I added it after last OR, but I think it doesn't apply as a strict rule. I don't want any results which has privacy lower than 3. Should I put it next to where?

Comment: You would need put parenthesis around the OR searches like in my update.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I actually learned few things. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938155/mysql-select-based-on-friendship-status-of-current-user-with-searched-user

Comment: It looks like  ***AgRizzo*** figured it out and achieved what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did not misunderstand your problem. Correct me if I am wrong some where.

```
SELECT u.name_surname,
       u.avatar,
       u.location
FROM USERS AS U
INNER JOIN CONNECTIONS AS C
ON  C.USER_ID = U.ID
INNER JOIN WORDS_EN AS W
ON  W.ID = C.WORD_ID
AND W.WORD LIKE 'word1%'
```

I have hard coded word1 for example, you can also make `INNER JOIN` of `WORDS_EN` as `LEFT JOIN` if you need all user information's having connections regardless of their words in WORDS_EN.

Comment: Yes, this works, but what I want to do is search for users using keyword that can appear in location, name_surname, or words_en. This query deals with words_en, but I need it united with my original query.