# Mysql select based on friendship status of current user with searched user

Tags: mysql, sql

sql fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60689e/12

Query at the moment looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name_surname, u.avatar, u.location
FROM users AS u
  JOIN connections AS c ON c.user_id = u.id
  JOIN words_en AS w ON w.id = c.word_id
WHERE (w.word = :kwd
  OR u.location = :kwd
  OR u.name_surname = :kwd)
AND u.privacy > 0
AND c.deleted <> 1
```

It is a search query for user, that looks into location name_surname and words and shows user that owns this keyword anywhere in those columns.

I would like to incorporate current user and searched user relationship in this query somehow.

u.privacy can be 0,2,3. 0 means private and is omitted from search results. 2 is friends only. And 3 is everybody. I'm having hard time incorporate this privacy = 2 part. So if found users privacy setting is 2, than I've to compare their relationship and if they are friends show searched user, if not don't display him.

Relationship is stored as a two way stream, in friends table.

This is query I use to select all person1's friends:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f1.asked_user_id) AS friend_id
FROM friends AS f1 JOIN friends AS f2
    ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
   AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
  AND f1.asker_user_id = :person1
```

Any help appreciated!
thanks!

## UPDATE

```
SELECT (u.id) as uuid, u.avatar, u.location, u.name_surname,
MAX(CONCAT_WS(", ",
    CASE WHEN w.word = :kwd THEN "words list" END,
    CASE WHEN u.location = :kwd THEN "location" END,
    CASE WHEN u.name_surname = :kwd THEN "name" END)) As matched
FROM users AS u
JOIN connections AS c
  ON c.user_id = u.id
JOIN words_en AS w 
  ON w.id = c.word_id
LEFT JOIN friends AS f1
  ON f1.asker_user_id = :user_id
    AND f1.status = 1
    AND f1.asked_user_id = u.id
WHERE (w.word = :kwd
  OR u.location = :kwd
  OR u.name_surname = :kwd)
AND (u.privacy = 3 OR (u.privacy = 2 and f1.id IS NOT NULL))
AND c.deleted <> 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY matched DESC
```

This query works, but if user has no word at all in connections, than even if match is positive in location select returns nothing.

Comment: Please describe how you set up your friends table?  I think you need to LEFT JOIN to the friends table ON both the users.id (the FROM table) and the actual user of who is running the query.  Then in your WHERE clause replace `u.privacy>0` with `(u.privacy=3 OR (u.privacy=2 AND friends.ID IS NOT NULL))`

Comment: In the friends table, (116,1,3,1,'2013-11-05 20:09:48'); and (113,3,1,1,'2013-11-05 19:12:10'), are mutual friends. 3 is 1 friend and 1 is 3 friend.

Comment: @AgRizzo updated OP with more details, also check comment above. Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load better data in your SQLFiddle.  All of the users had privacy set to 0. Also, once you load the data, let me know what the values of person1 and kwd need to be to get results in your sample data

**Changed to take into consideration no words/connections**

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name_surname, u.avatar, u.location
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN connections AS c
  ON c.user_id = u.id
    AND c.deleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN words_en AS w 
  ON w.id = c.word_id
LEFT JOIN friends AS f1
  ON f1.asker_user_id = :person1
    AND f1.status=1
    AND f1.asked_user_id = u.uid
WHERE (w.word = :kwd
  OR u.location = :kwd
  OR u.name_surname = :kwd)
AND (u.privacy=3 OR (u.privacy=2 and f1.id IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tested this, and the result has 1 problem, if user has no words-connections but match still exists in location for example, it returns nothing. Please see updated post with current query I use.

Comment: @salivan - Changed it above.  The `LEFT JOIN` will allow you to match users when there is no connections/words

Comment: Here is an example user 5 has Milan in location, but he is not in the list because connections has no row with that id: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c79a6/1

Comment: @salivan - All fixed (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c79a6/8)  The connections.deleted logic has been moved to the join (The other option was to change the `AND c.deleted<>1` to `AND (c.deleted<>1 OR c.deleted IS NULL)`